# Порядок выполнения скрипта

Tags: javascript

```
<p>ASdsffffffffffD</p> 

<script src="main.js"></script> 

<p>dasdfffffffffffffs</p>
```

Вот при таком выполнение сначала должен показаться первый параграф на странице, потом выполнится скрипт, и только потом покажется последний параграф. А у меня сначала загружается скрипт , а потом только показываются все параграфы.

P.S.Залил на jsfiddle, всё работает как надо, показался первый параграф, потом выполнился скрипт, и.т.д. А запускаю на компе у себя, так сразу выполняется скрипт...

Comment: почему ты думаешь, что сразу выполняется скрипт?

Comment: Ну потому что информация на странице появляется после исполнения скрипта.

Comment: есть ли еще какой-то код, который ты используешь на своей странице? какой код внутри main.js? Ты на глаз определял что скрип выполняется сначала?

Comment: Да, на глаз)) Кода больше нет, внутри просто алерт.

Comment: и почему ты решил, что он выполняется сначала?

Comment: Ну потому что информация на странице появляется после исполнения скрипта.

Comment: это забавно, но проблема именно в alert :) Все по прежнему выполняется в правильном порядке, просто из-за блокирующего вызова alert не успевает прорисоваться первый элемент `p` при этом он уже доступен в скрипте `main`

Comment: кроме того такое поведение похоже только в chrome: в EDGE и FF - ожидаемо выводится первый абзац

Comment: В Opera та же проблема!

Comment: Опера на том же движке, что и Chrome